# How call a CloudDeployed function with more than a parameter

Tags: cloud-deploy

With only one parameter `api = CloudDeploy[funccc]` get the urrl

```
CloudObject["https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/66bca81d-7dfa-4e56-bd37-\
68357ffa0fec"]
```

call the url finished with ?x=308 and done but how to put not only x  but also y=11 and z = 10 ??

Comment: Take a look at URLBuild but e.g. URLExecute does it too

Comment: @Kuba well   this is to call function from Mathematica ...the concern is to use this function in the cloud from any browser in a tablet or a cellular ...   without Mathematica

Comment: Then URLBuild will show you the syntax you can use.

Comment: @Kuba Thanks I got it   put & between different parameter specifications!